# Kotlin - Passing args through Fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, fragment, args

I have a problem with my app. It has 3 Fragments ( F1 + F2 + F3)

In F1 (receives a list with x numbers of sports) and the user should select one (a RecyclerView is used to present the data).
On F2 (recevies a list of equipment) and the user should select the equipment ( a RecyclerView is used also)
In F3 I want to resume the users choices. I've tried to use ShareViewModel but every time I tried to use this, it appears as null in F3.

What is the best way to pass this args??! `SharedViewModel` ou using SafeArgs?! I've tried to use a `SharedViewModel`.

*Be aware that the following code has not been copy from android studio, it might contain some execution errors.*

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemview.text=listsports[position]

        holder.itemview.setOnClickListener{
    
        val sViewModel=SharedViewModel()
    
        sViewModel.setSport(adapterposition)
    
        v:View->v.findNavcontroller().navigate(R.id.action_F1_to_F2)}
    }
}
```

And the `ShareViewModel` is like:

```
class SharedViewModel():ViewModel(){

var selectSport= MutableLiveData<String>
val _selectSports=LiveData<String>
get()=selectSport


fun setSport(index:Int)
{
    selectSport.value=listsports[position].toString()
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using:

```
val sViewModel=SharedViewModel()
```

try using:

```
val sViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

in every of your fragment

cf: the documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Comment: The problem is that i'm trying to pass the value to the ShareViewModel inside the RecyclerViewClass.
It shows *Unresolved reference: activityViewModels*

Comment: I guess you mean inside the adapter? You can pass the fragment in the constructor of the recyclerview if so